# Flex Box Columns vs Rows

Tags: css, flexbox

```js
$(".logo").hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.partner').find('.info').slideDown();
}, function() {
  $('.info').slideUp();
});
```

```css
#partnerBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.partner {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 40px 0px #00000014;
}

.logo {
  height: 150px;
}

.info {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="partnerBox">
  <div class="partner">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="partner">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="partner">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="partner">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="partner">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="partner">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="partner">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="partner">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="partner">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the box to show the extra div on hover (which it does at the moment). However, when it shows the div I want it to push down the column its in, not the row.

I would normally be able to do this using the bootstrap columns but I determined to stick to flex box

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/915957/

Comment: The "new" div is expanding the height of the row...there's not much you can do about that other than switching to a column layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by adding a 'column' wrapper. Easiest solution i could find, maybe there is a more optimal way.

If you want 3 columns, just add a .col class and wrap the content of that column in there

```
.col {
  flex: 1;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div id="partnerBox">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="partner">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <div class="info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <div class="info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <div class="info"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
     <div class="partner">
       <div class="logo"></div>
       <div class="info"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="partner">
       <div class="logo"></div>
       <div class="info"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="partner">
       <div class="logo"></div>
       <div class="info"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
     <div class="partner">
       <div class="logo"></div>
       <div class="info"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="partner">
       <div class="logo"></div>
       <div class="info"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="partner">
       <div class="logo"></div>
       <div class="info"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonaspraem/xpvt214o/916163/)

Notice that this quickfix breaks your styling a little bit, you need to adjust the width a bit.

Comment: It also breaks the order of your list - I don't know if that is relevant ?

Comment: Amazing. Such a simple solution too! Thanks for this :)